# Data Filter on time

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters

I have a data extension with a date field. I want to create a filtered data extension that filters data for the past hour. Can I create a filer that filters on the time part of the date field?

Comment: You likely will need to do so via a Query and not the UI filter functionality.

Comment: I'm new to exact target. Are queries the same as a Data Extract?

Comment: A query is basically just a SQL select statement run against a Data Exension or Data View (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Comment: To help others with the same question, it would be great if you could put a sample of your full solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

select [field_target ]from [DATAEXTENSION ]WHERE [DATETIME FIELD] >=  DATEADD(hour, -1, GETDATE())